# If a struct has a Vector field, does it get allocated on the heap?

Tags: rust, heap-memory, stack-memory

Suppose I have a struct `Train` which contains a field called `passenger_ids` which itself represents a Vector of passenger identifiers.

```
struct Train {
  passenger_ids: Vector<u32>
}
```

Would `Train` be allocated on the heap since it holds a field of type Vector (which is allocated on the heap)? Or would it instead be allocated on the stack and the field point towards the heap?

Comment: Only the `u32`s in the vector are necessarily stored on the heap.

Comment: Are you coming from C#?  If so, the whole concept of "primitives are on the stack, but classes are on the heap, structs can be weird" (I know that's a broad generalization) is not a thing in Rust.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I mainly work in NodeJs. I was reading a bit on stack and the heap and my general understanding was. "If it has a known size at compile time -> it's on the stack and if it does not then it's on the heap". It's a pretty naive approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would Train be allocated on the heap since it holds a field of type Vector (which is allocated on the heap)? Or would it instead be allocated on the stack and the field point towards the heap?

No, a train would not be allocated on the heap, and no a vector is not allocated on the heap.

A `Vec` is a normal structure which *contains* a pointer to a heap allocation. The `Train`, and the `Vec` it contains, will be allocated as a single unit wherever they are put (whether that's on the stack, or on the heap if `Box`-ed, or somewhere else).

The `Vec` will then, if and when items get added to it, create a heap allocation and put the items there.